# How to write to a document and read the id of it within a single transaction in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, transactions

I am doing the user authentication where I have this case:

1. Read from `vendor_type` document and if it returns null(doesn't exist) then continue the transaction,
2. Create new user using `.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)`,
3. Read the new users ID,
4. Write to `vendor_type` document some of the new user's detail such as **name**, **surname**, **userId** -->> *userId is the problem, how can I create a user and get the ID within a single transaction, can I even do that*? ,
5. Take the newly created ID of the user, and create a new `vendor` document with that ID.

So far I don't have any code to post because I don't know if this is even gonna work so I didn't start. If you have any idea how to implement this, please let me know. The main issue is getting the user ID while still in the transaction.

Comment: Why do you need a transaction here?  What situation are you trying to avoid?

Comment: @DougStevenson I changed my approach, now I am registering new user first then posting to other documents later after the user is signed in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of writing, it is not possible to combine **in one transaction** the creation of a user through the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` method from the Auth service **AND** a write to the Firestore service.

They are two different services offered by Firestore and therefore you cannot combined calls to these two different services in one transaction.

Comment: Alright, how can I get the user ID when creating user BUT without signing in first because when I create a user with email it signs in automatically and that will break the continuous chain of operations.

Comment: I think I cant get the user id without signing in first, thats still fine I guess. I just wont redirect to another page because that will break the operation. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You may be interested by this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-an-admin-module-for-managing-users-access-and-roles-34a94cf31a6e) which presents how to build, with a Callable Cloud Function, a module for allowing end-users with a specific Admin role creating other users (disclaimer, I'm the author). By using a Cloud Function you don't sign in the new user.

Comment: When you call the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` method from a client (i.e. through a Client SDK), the new user is automatically signed in. There isn't any way to prevent this.

Comment: Thanks for sharing it but I changed my approach so now I actually want the user to be able to register and sign in before he can continue registration with other extra information which he can do it later at any time.

Comment: Please upvote my question if you think it can help others who need similar help.